# Why do Integral Schemes have Normalizations?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I know that affine integral schemes $\text{Spec} R$ have normalizations- namely the spectrum of the integral closure of $R$ in its field of fraction. However,  how do we know normalizations exist for a general integral scheme $X$? Probably we would like to take a cover of $X$ by affine opens $U_{\alpha}$ and then glue their normalizations $\widetilde{U_{\alpha}}$. But how should we glue them?

Comment: The gluing is natural and you can't go wrong.

Comment: Instead of the absolute spectrum of a ring, you can take the relative spectrum of a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-algebras. More concretely you take the subsheaf of the constant sheaf $K(X)$ consisting of sections integral over $\mathcal O_X$. Then you take the relative spectrum.